# OpenMP C++ handles complex for loop parallelism

Tags: c++, openmp

I am working on this legacy C++ code and trying to apply OpenMP to the code. The code has many for loop calculations which involves many element indexes stored in global variables. I am struggling to use different ways to handle these complex for loop parallelism but found out it was difficult to improve the performance by using OpenMP techniques. Take a look at the following snippet:

```
    for (i=0;i<NBeams;i++)  // NBeams is very large number
    {
        for (j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            k = BeamConn[i][j];  // BeamConn stores the indexes for each item of NBeams
            ix[k-1] = 6; 
        }
       if (BeamConn[i][0] < k) 
            k = BeamConn[i][0];
        
        for (j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            m = BeamConn[i][j];
            if (k < jmin[m-1])          
                jmin[m-1] = k;              
        }   
    }
```

Firstly I tried to encapsulate inner loops as a function and pass the parameters to the function and implement the for loop parallelism on the outer loop:

```
void skdd_inner(vector<int> jmin, int i, int m, int k)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
  {
     k = BeamConn[i][j];
     ix[k - 1] = 6;
  }
  if (BeamConn[i][0] < k)
     k = BeamConn[i][0];

  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
  {
     m = BeamConn[i][j];
     if (k < jmin[m - 1])
        jmin[m - 1] = k;
  }
}
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(i) shared(m, jmin, k)
for(i = 0; i < NBeams; i++)
{
   skdd_inner(jmin, i, m, k);
}
```

However the above parallelism didn't work: the results were not correct. The problems are that jmin, k, m are global variable shared during the parallelism, also for these inner loops the jmin depends on k and k can be overwritten by BeamConn. Then I got rid of this encapsulated function and tried other ways for this complex for loop parallelism and ended up with the following workshares construct in order to get the correct results:

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered default(none) private(i,j) shared(m, jmin, BeamConn, k, ix)
        for (i = 0; i < NBeams; i++)
        {           
          #pragma omp ordered
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    k = BeamConn[i][j];
                    ix[k - 1] = 6;
                }


                if (BeamConn[i][0] < k)
                    k = BeamConn[i][0];

                for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    m = BeamConn[i][j];
                    if (k < jmin[m - 1])
                        jmin[m - 1] = k;
                }
            }                           
        }
```

I knew that the order construct is very expensive and best way is to avoid the ordered construct in for parallel loop. But for my case, it seems that the order construct is the only way to get the correct results. My questions are: do I have better way to improve this OpenMP code with better performance and getting the correct results at the same time?  is it worth using OpenMP code for this type of complex for loop which involves dependencies between the variables inside the inner loop? The example codes in OpenMP API 5.2 only give relative simple for loop parallelism cases. For complex for loop case like this, I can not figure out the better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Since `k`, `m` and `jmin` are accessed by multiple threads for both reading and writing, sharing them would result in a race condition.

Comment: It looks like each `i` iteration starts by setting `k`, so it doesn't carry over from iteration to the next, so you should make it private. Similarly I think `ix` can be made private.

Comment: The first step should be optimizing your serial code. How is `BeamConn` stored in memory? I believe the greatest speed increase could be achieved by rewriting your code to make it easier to vectorize. For example, you could use two 1D arrays, such as `BeamConn0` and `BeamConn1`, which may be efficiently vectorized.